# How to pull source code of an https protocol website

Tags: linux, wget

How do I pull down the source code of a page of a website that is using https protocol using wget or curl ?

Comment: What doesn't work? What did you try?

Comment: I am trying to pull source code of https://jobs3.netmedia1.com/cp/search_results.jsp through wget but the result is displayed in encrypted format. How should one go about it to display the source code in human readable format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both wget and curl can get pages over https, but they need to have been compiled with SSL support.

References:

1. [Wget HTTPS (SSL/TLS) Options Reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options.html) (Wget must be compiled with OpenSSL)
2. [curl FAQ](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#curl_1_SSL_is_disabled_https)
3. [How to build curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html)